# dplyr if else without the else

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where I'm trying to change the values of some variables based on a different variable with an if else statement.  However, I only want to change the variable if a certain condition is met - otherwise I want the variable to be unchanged.  How do I do this in dplyr?

e.g., if I have 4 sites (a, b, c and d), that are each associated with a value of 10, 20, 30 and 40, respectively, and I just want to change the value of 10 at site a to 12.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(lat = ifelse(site == "a", 12, WHAT GOES HERE?))
```

Comment: Another option would be `replace`: `mutate(df, lat = replace(lat, site == "a", 12))`

Comment: Very helpful to know another option  Thanks Markus!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(lat = ifelse(site == "a", 12, lat))
```

Comment: what if lat has no previous value?

Comment: Sorry, I'd need an example question to clearly follow what you mean. Could you create a new question with some example data and/or elaborate on your comment?